# Scenario Automation to automate an android game

Tags: java, android, python, selenium

I am trying to find out which is the best possible way that i can achieve automation for a game which has the same thing to be done over and over again.

I want to write the automation to have scenario based execution.
For Eg :

Energy is a variable , When it reaches full - it should run dungeons until it can't then stop.

Arena Tries is another variable , When it reaches a certain level , it should run arena and then stop.

Tower of Trial Attempts is another variable which has 5 tries , it should do it for 5 times , different level's each time then stop.

So how is it possible to do this?.
1) how can i retrieve the data from the Android Emulator - NOX/BLUESTACK into the program.

2) how to make a program to just run in the background , like a headless application? 

3) which is the tool/language can be used to make it possible? I know python and Java.

Thanks.

Comment: Here is an example using Python with Appium (which runs on top of Selendroid): http://bitbar.com/how-to-use-image-recognition-for-mobile-app-and-game-testing/ and OpenCV for graphical feature detection.